# create PySpark Dataframe column based on class method

Tags: python, function, class, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a python class and it has functions like below:

```
class Features():
    def __init__(self, json):
        self.json = json

    def get_email(self):
        email = self.json.get('fields', {}).get('email', None)
        return email
```

And I am trying to use the get_email function in a pyspark dataframe to create a new column based on another column, "raw_json",which consists of json value:

```
df = data.withColumn('email', (F.udf(lambda j: Features.get_email(json.loads(j)), t.StringType()))('raw_json'))
```

So the ideal  pyspark dataframe looks like below:

```
 +---------------+-----------
 |raw_json         |email
 +----------------+----------
 |                 |  
 +----------------+--------
 |                 |  
 +----------------+-------
```

But I am getting an error saying:

```
TypeError: unbound method get_email() must be called with Features instance as first argument (got dict instance instead)
```

How should I do to achieve this?

I have seen a similar question asked before but it was not resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have misunderstood how classes are used in Python. You're probably looking for this instead:

```
udf = F.udf(lambda j: Features(json.loads(j)).get_email())
df = data.withColumn('email', udf('raw_json'))
```

where you instantiate a `Features` object and call the `get_email` method of the object.

Comment: How can I apply the function on the "raw_json" column though..?

Comment: Have you tried `Features = Features()` first, then use `data.withColumn('email', Features.get_email(col("raw_json"))`?

Comment: @XXavier i got this error when doing Features = Features(): TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: @kihhfeue I edited my answer to let you apply on the raw_json column. Your error of not defined parse_date is irrelevant to my suggestion - it's something else that is wrong in your code.